# How to convert Set to Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, syntax, ecmascript-harmony

**Set** seems like a nice way to create Arrays with guaranteed unique elements, but it does not expose any good way to get properties, except for generator [Set].values, which is called in an awkward way of `mySet.values.next()`.

This would have been ok, if you could call `map` and similar functions on Sets. But you cannot do that, as well.

I've tried `Array.from`, but seems to be converting only array-like (NodeList and TypedArrays ?) objects to Array. Another try: `Object.keys` does not work for Sets, and Set.prototype does not have similar static method.

So, the question: **Is there any convenient inbuilt method for creating an Array with values of a given Set ?** (Order of element does not really matter).

if no such option exists, then maybe there is a nice idiomatic one-liner for doing that ? like, using `for...of`, or similar ?

Comment: dear ESNext/ECMAScript people, there is no reason not to have filter/map/reduce on Map/Set, ty :)

Answer (score 1508, accepted):

> if no such option exists, then maybe there is a nice idiomatic
> one-liner for doing that ? like, using `for...of`, or similar ?

Indeed, there are several ways to convert a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

- *Using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):*

Note: safer for TypeScript.

```
const array = Array.from(mySet);
```

- *Simply [`spreading`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the Set out in an array:*

Note: Spreading a Set has issues when compiled with TypeScript (See [issue #8856](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856)). It's safer to use `Array.from` above instead.

```
const array = [...mySet];
```

- *The old-fashioned way, iterating and pushing to a new array (Sets do have `forEach`):*

```
const array = [];
mySet.forEach(v => array.push(v));
```

- *Previously, using the non-standard, and now deprecated array comprehension syntax:*

```
const array = [v for (v of mySet)];
```

Comment: `var array = [v for (v of mySet)];` does not work in [tag:Chrome] 46

Comment: looks like chrome supports as of 45
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#AutoCompatibilityTable

Comment: Also, the last one is using this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions, which is a non-standard and deprecated feature

Comment: which way is better?

Comment: Just wanted to add that `[...mySet]` has issues when compiled using Typescript (see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856)), so probably safer to use `Array.from(mySet)` if you intend to convert to Typescript in the near future.

Comment: Spread operator returns a [Set(3)] instead of ['a','b','c'] only on production, on dev environment it looks ok, any idea why? Maybe something because uglification or something other in webpack?
Array.from() solves this issue.

Comment: By the way, if anyone is concerned about speed, here's a ranking from fastest to slowest: #1. old-fashioned (forEach/for of); #2. Array.from (~5% slower); #3. spreading (~12% slower)

Comment: @Pumych If you use babel to transpile your code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71021389/babel-incorrect-transformation-of-spread/71021566 and https://github.com/jaredpalmer/tsdx/issues/376#issuecomment-566750042 may help you.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that array comprehension was ever a thing in JavaScript.

Answer (score 101):

via https://speakerdeck.com/anguscroll/es6-uncensored by Angus Croll

It turns out, we can use `spread` operator:

```
var myArr = [...mySet];
```

Or, alternatively, use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
var myArr = Array.from(mySet);
```

Comment: refer to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ for more or less up-to-date support chart. Currently, of all desktop browsers, only FF and IE TP (aka Spartan, aka MS Non-IE browser) support `Array.from` and `...`

Comment: Looks like Firefox is the only browser to support `Array.from`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: Here you can enable it for Chrome `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony` Remember it's experimental don't think for moment that this is a good solution for development.

Comment: If my set is of objects, does using the `spread` syntax clone the set, or does it keep the object references? (I want to call methods in these objects so I need them to be the same, not clones)

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you are just using `Set` temporarily to get unique values in an array and then converting back to an Array, try using this:

```
_.uniq([])
```

This relies on using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) or [lo-dash](https://lodash.com/).

Comment: Unluckily the only cross-broser solution

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps to late to the party, but you could just do the following:

```
const set = new Set(['a', 'b']);
const values = set.values();
const array = Array.from(values);
```

This should work without problems in browsers that have support for ES6 or if you have a shim that correctly polyfills the above functionality.

**Edit**: Today you can just use what @c69 suggests:

```
const set = new Set(['a', 'b']);
const array = [...set]; // or Array.from(set)
```

Comment: It seems that using the `set.entries()` you will get array of pairs. You can use `set.values()` to get the plain array.

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko true, and the user did ask for that.

Comment: You can just use `var array = Array.from(set);`

Comment: this answer is just wrong. You don't need the call to `.entries`, nor `.values`. As @Buffalo mentioned above - `Array.from(set)` is enough.

Comment: @c69 that is true. At the time of this answer, `Array.from()` did not work as expected. But now spread and `Array.from()` both work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The code below creates a set from an array and then, using the `...` operator.

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,];
var set=new Set(arr);
let setarr=[...set];
console.log(setarr);
```

Comment: ..and this is what?

Comment: This is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which is actually 2 different operations (1) within objects (2) arrays / function argument lists.  The latter follows "iteration protocols": it calls the [Symbol.iterator method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/@@iterator), then does the whole next() dance. P.S. `...` also appears in 2 similar [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was:

```
var testSet = new Set();
var testArray = [];

testSet.add("1");
testSet.add("2");
testSet.add("2"); // duplicate item
testSet.add("3");

var someFunction = function (value1, value2, setItself) {
    testArray.push(value1);
};

testSet.forEach(someFunction);

console.log("testArray: " + testArray);
```

[value1 equals value2 => The value contained in the the current position in the Set. The same value is passed for both arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach)

Worked under IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Set** and converting it to an array is very similar to copying an Array...

So you can use the same methods for copying an array which is very easy in **ES6**

For example, you can use `...`

Imagine you have this Set below:

```
const a = new Set(["Alireza", "Dezfoolian", "is", "a", "developer"]);
```

You can simply convert it using:

```
const b = [...a];
```

and the result is:

```
["Alireza", "Dezfoolian", "is", "a", "developer"]
```

An array and now you can use all methods that you can use for an array...

Other common ways of doing it:

```
const b = Array.from(a);
```

or using loops like:

```
const b = [];
a.forEach(v => b.push(v));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to start with removing duplications from an array and then try to sort.
Return the 1st element from new array.

```
    function processData(myArray) {
        var s = new Set(myArray);
        var arr = [...s];
        return arr.sort((a,b) => b-a)[1];
    }
    
    console.log(processData([2,3,6,6,5]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an easy way to get only unique raw values from array. If you convert the array to Set and after this, do the conversion from Set to array. This conversion works only for raw values, for objects in the array it is not valid. Try it by yourself.

```
    let myObj1 = {
        name: "Dany",
        age: 35,
        address: "str. My street N5"
    }

    let myObj2 = {
        name: "Dany",
        age: 35,
        address: "str. My street N5"
    }

    var myArray = [55, 44, 65, myObj1, 44, myObj2, 15, 25, 65, 30];
    console.log(myArray);

    var mySet = new Set(myArray);
    console.log(mySet);

    console.log(mySet.size === myArray.length);// !! The size differs because Set has only unique items

    let uniqueArray = [...mySet];
    console.log(uniqueArray); 
    // Here you will see your new array have only unique elements with raw 
    // values. The objects are not filtered as unique values by Set.
    // Try it by yourself.
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function countUniqueValues(arr) {
  return Array.from(new Set(arr)).length 

}

console.log(countUniqueValues([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 12, 12, 13]))
```

Comment: The question explicitly asks for an array, not a length. But the method covered here to convert the Set is already covered in the other answers. Not sure what this answer really adds.