# Convert a Javascript `Set` to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, ecmascript-6

There doesn't seem to be an easy and elegant way of converting a Javascript `Set` to an array.

```
var set = new Set();
set.add("Hello");
set.add("There");
set.add(complexObject);

var setConvertedToArray = convertSetToArray(set);

console.log( setConvertedToArray ); // ["Hello", "There", ►Object ]
```

A `map` feels about right, but the `Set` prototype only has a `forEach`.

Yuck:

```
function convertSetToArray(set) {
  var a = [];
  set.forEach( x => a.push(x) ); 
  return a;
}
```

Anyone know of a nice way to convert a `Set` to an array?

Comment: Or better one [How to convert Set to Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some ways to do it:

```
[...set];
[...set.keys()];
[...set.values()];
Array.from(set);
Array.from(set.keys());
Array.from(set.values());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method which returns an array from Array like objects like `Set`

```js
var set = new Set();
set.add("Hello");
set.add("There");
set.add({});

var setConvertedToArray = Array.from(set);

document.body.innerHTML = setConvertedToArray instanceof Array;
```