# Group objects by common property merging the rest of properties as separate objects within array

Tags: javascript

this is my input, i have an array where name key has value 'foo1' in multiple objects so i want unique object with respect to 'name' key value and other information on a separate array.

```
var array = [{
    name: "foo1",
    value: "val1",
    status: "1"
  }, {
    name: "foo1",
    value:  "val2",
    status: "0"
  }, {
    name: "foo1",
    value:  "val3",
    status: "1"
  }, {
    name: "foo2",
    value: "val4",
    status: "1"
  }];
```

and i want on output like below. Below array are unique by name key and other value and status key from all matching object store on new_obj key.

```
var output = [{
  name: "foo1",
  new_obj: [{
      value:"val1", 
      status: "1"
    }, {
      value:"val2", 
      status: "0"
    }, {
      value:"val3", 
      status: "1"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "foo2",
    new_obj: [{
      value:"val4", 
      status: "1"
    }]  
  }];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You have to attempt this yourself, and if you encounter any problems, we will be glqad to help.

Comment: Take a look at this to understand how to ask a good question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344976/collect-unique-objects-in-javascript-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collect unique objects in JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344976/collect-unique-objects-in-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build up (e.g. using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), having `name` values as keys and grouped objects as values, so once you find the `name` that was already seen ([`Map.prototype.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) does not return `undefined` by respective key), you push the rest of properties as a separate object to `new_obj`, if encountered `name` was not seen before, you create (with [`Map.prototype.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set)) grouped object for that.

As your `Map` is ready, you extract its values with [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) into array, using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const arr = [{name:"foo1",value:"val1",status:"1"},{name:"foo1",value:"val2",status:"0"},{name:"foo1",value:"val3",status:"1"},{name:"foo2",value:"val4",status:"1"}],
    
    result = [...arr
      .reduce((acc, {name, ...rest}) => {
          const group = acc.get(name)
          group ? group.new_obj.push(rest) : acc.set(name, {name, "new_obj":[rest]})
          return acc
        }, new Map)
      .values()
    ]
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var output = array.reduce((acc, value) => {
  if (!acc[value.name]) acc[value.name] = {
    name: value.name,
    new_obj: []
  };
  acc[value.name].new_obj.push({value: value.value, status: value.status});
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a oneliner for this using lodash

```
_.groupBy(array, 'name')
```