# NodeJS how to add objects to a set and iterate?

Tags: node.js, loops, object, set

This should be really straightforward but i haven't got it to work.

```
var Set = require("collections/set");

function User() {
    this.name = 'something';
}

var clients = new Set();

var a = new User();
var b = new User();
clients.add(a);
clients.add(b);

var arr = clients.toArray();
for (var user in arr) {
    console.log(user.name+' iterated');
}
```

Why am i getting:

```
undefined iterated
undefined iterated
```

What i want to get is:

```
something iterated
something iterated
```

Comment: Also if i skip the array and just do directly:
for (var user in clients)

Then i get "undefined iterated" about 50 times.

Comment: i think you're meant to use `of` instead of `in`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array any of these ways work?

Comment: "of" is an Unexpected identifier, checking the link now

Comment: `Array.from(clients)` should work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var Set = require("collections/set");

function User() {
    this.name = 'something';
}


var clients = new Set();

var a = new User();
var b = new User();
clients.add(a);
clients.add(b);


var arr = clients.toArray();
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].name+" iterated");
}
//something iterated
//something iterated
```

Comment: I do not need to require Set in NodeJS version 12. It was throwing an error when i did. It is available by default

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `of` instead of `in` in your for loop. `in` loops through fields on an object, which is why you get like 50 lines with the set object. `of` on the other hand will treat the target like an iterator and grab its contents like you would expect. Here is an example:

```js
function User() {
    this.name = 'something';
}

var clients = new Set();

var a = new User();
var b = new User();
clients.add(a);
clients.add(b);

for (var user of clients) {
    console.log(user.name+' iterated');
}
```

(I am assuming that your `collections/set` thing is smart enough to expose the iterator symbol thing that makes it work)

Comment: Doesn't look like it's smart enough, i am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - On the "of" part.

Comment: Then do what sumeet has posted, that will work if you can get an actual array.