# Remove repeated elements from v-for in VueJS

Tags: vue-component, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm using the following code to display categories from an array. The array may contain duplicate categories. Is there any way I can only select unique elements in VueJS?

```
<li v-for="product in products">
{{product.category}}
</li>
```

Array:

```
products: [
      { id: '1', title: 'Test 1', category: 'Test 3' },
      { id: '2', title: 'Test 2', category: 'Test 1' },
      { id: '3', title: 'Test 3', category: 'Test 2' },
      { id: '3', title: 'Test 4', category: 'Test 1' },
      { id: '5', title: 'Test 5', category: 'Test 3' }
    ]
```

Comment: It's an array, so filter it for duplicate values. Maybe use [`_.uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie in VueJS. I heard there is no filter option in vuejs2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a computed property with the unique values you want. If you include Lodash in your project, try [`_.uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniq)

```
import uniq from 'lodash/uniq'
// ...snip

computed: {
  productCategories () {
    return uniq(this.products.map(({ category }) => category))
  }
}
```

and in your template

```
<li v-for="category in productCategories">
  {{category}}
</li>
```

---

If you're not keen on introducing Lodash (or other utility libraries), the same can be achieved with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
productCategories () {
  return [...new Set(this.products.map(({ category }) => category))]
}
```

*Note*: I've [converted the `Set` to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array) as Vue.js doesn't seem able to iterate the `Set` (or any other `Iterator`).

Comment: ok. Great a thanks. But what is that '...' before? Is that a javascript syntax or vuejs?

Comment: @Gijo that's the JavaScript *spread* operator. You can also use `Array.from` (see the linked post)

Comment: @phil How can I get and output the other properties of a product? I made a Codepen to demonstrate the issue https://codepen.io/jmar/pen/eEYGXW

Comment: @jmartsch I suggest you open a new question

Answer (score 2):

You can create a computed property: `uniqProducts` which will return unique array for your `products`, you will need to make following changes:

**HTML**

```
<li v-for="product in uniqProducts">
  {{product.category}}
</li>
```

in **vue** instance you have to write a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) which can use any technique (many listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)) to get uniq array.

`_` here can be [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq).

```
computed: {
   uniqProducts () {
      return _.uniqBy(this.products, 'property')
   }
}
```

Comment: but how does this take 'unique' products? on what basis?

Comment: @GijoVarghese I have started to use `uniqProducts` in the HTML, which will get unique array from computed property, you can pass the property on which you want uniqeness.

Comment: I can create unique separate from backend easy. I was wondering if its possible in vuejs to select unique from a JSON like complex array. I will update the question with array I've