# The most efficient way to convert a javascript set to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion, set

Is there a way of converting a Set to a String directly (without first converting the set to an array)? I have gone through the documentation at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and I feel they may be a  way of doing it. This is what I do:

```
let myset = new Set();
myset.add(3);
myset.add(" Wise ");
myset.add(" Men ");

let setStr = myset.toString();
let setArrStr = Array.from(myset).toString();

console.log("Set to String: " + setStr );  //"Set to String: [object Set]"
console.log("Set to Array to String: " + setArrStr);  // "Set to Array to String: 3, Wise , Men "
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doing it"? Do you want to print every element of the set separated by a comma?

Comment: how should the string look like?

Comment: Thanks @Nina I just want it converted to a string directly. Must it be converted to an array first?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this seems to be a dublicate with pretty good answers already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Set to Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array)

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius I dont think so. Convert Set => String is not the same as Convert Set to Array as you cited.

Comment: You need array to get string or loop over values(). Shortest is `[...myset].join()`

Answer (score 3):

You **can** convert to string directly like so:

```js
let string = "";
let myset = new Set();
myset.add(3);
myset.add(" Wise ");
myset.add(" Men ");

myset.forEach(value => string += value);
console.log(string); // → "3 Wise  Men "
```

Hope you got your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Or more compact, via an array...

```
let myset = new Set();
myset.add(3);
myset.add("Wise");
myset.add("Men");

console.log(Array.from(myset).join('')); // → "3WiseMen"
console.log(Array.from(myset).join(' ')); // → "3 Wise Men"
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked "without first converting the set to an array".