# Union between three arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need to find the union of three arrays that get passed to the function `union`.

It took me about 50lines to code to get the expected result. Apparently, the following code works but now I wonder what are the best ways (either in a functional and in a non-functional fashion) to do the same job.

```
function union(...arrays) {
    var array1 = arguments[0];
    var array2 = arguments[1];
    var array3 = arguments[2];      

    var unique = [];
    var intersaction = [];

    // find the unique values

    for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if( (array2.includes(array1[i]) == false) && (array3.includes(array1[i])) == false ) {
            unique.push(array1[i]); 
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        if( (array1.includes(array2[i]) == false) && (array3.includes(array2[i])) == false ) {
            unique.push(array2[i]); 
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
        if( (array1.includes(array3[i]) == false) && (array2.includes(array3[i])) == false ) {
            unique.push(array3[i]);
        }
    }

    // find the intersection

    for(let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        if(array2.includes(array1[j]) || array3.includes(array1[j]) ) {
            if (intersaction.indexOf(array1[j]) == -1) { 
                intersaction.push(array1[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    for(let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if(array1.includes(array2[j]) || array3.includes(array2[j]) ) {
            if (intersaction.indexOf(array2[j]) == -1) { 
                    intersaction.push(array2[j]);
            }       
        }
    }

    for(let j = 0; j < array3.length; j++) {
        if(array1.includes(array3[j]) || array2.includes(array3[j]) ) {
            if (intersaction.indexOf(array3[j]) == -1) { 
                    intersaction.push(array3[j]);
            }       
        }
    }

    return union = [...intersaction, ...unique];

}

console.log(union([5, 10, 15], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [100, 15, 10, 1, 5]));
// should log: [5, 10, 15, 88, 1, 7, 100]
```

Comment: Did you think about using **sets** instead? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/y03osape/1/ `Array.from(new Set([...arrays].flat()));`

Comment: What does mean _union_ for you? I would expect the result of `[5, 15]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just another solution keeping the original function signature provided by the OP:

```
function union(...arrays) {
    return Array.from(new Set([...arrays].flat()));
}

console.log(union([5, 10, 15], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [100, 15, 10, 1, 5]));
```

Or, even shorter (but less read friendly):

`return [...(new Set([...arrays].flat()))];`

Explanation:

- `Array.from` takes an Iterable as an argument, this will create a **new array** from the original one.
- `[...arrays]` spreads the arrays (argument) into a new, single, one (So it becomes an array of arrays) -> `[5, 10, 15], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [100, 15, 10, 1, 5]` becomes: `[[5, 10, 15], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [100, 15, 10, 1, 5]]`
- `.flat` flattens the array, making that an array of values rather than ar array of arrays of values -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat -> `[[5, 10, 15], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [100, 15, 10, 1, 5]]` becomes `[5, 10, 15, 15, 88, 1, 5, 7, 100, 15, 10, 1, 5]`
- `new Set` removes duplicates from the array and returns an Iterable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set. -> `[5, 10, 15, 15, 88, 1, 5, 7, 100, 15, 10, 1, 5]` becomes a Set instance (an Iterable) without the duplicates. Array.from then converts the Set (Iterable) to a regular array. Further infos here: [How to convert Set to Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array)

BEWARE: `Array.flat` is currently an experimental feature (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). Solution without using flat below:

```
function union(...arrays) {
    return Array.from(new Set([].concat.apply([],[...arrays])));
}

console.log(union([5, 10, 15], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [100, 15, 10, 1, 5]));
```

Explanation (only differences from above):

- Instead of .flat, we apply to `Array.concat` our original array, so that it will flatten it passing a new array as its `this` and providing our array as the argument: `[].concat.apply([],[...arrays])`

Snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/y03osape/2/

Snippet without `.flat`: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/y03osape/4/

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `.flat()` to anyone, since it's still an experimental api.

Comment: @kinduser you're right, indeed. I'll update with an alternative.

Comment: Use `[].concat(...arrays);` instead.

Comment: @kinduser yup, followed the `.apply` approach, I personally like it more. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5):

use [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) that's very simple,

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object

```js
var a=  [5, 10, 15];
var b=[15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
var c=[100, 15, 10, 1, 5];
var result= [...new Set([...a, ...b,...c])];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to copy your approach of looping over arrays but in a slightly more efficient manner, using only ES5 safe functions. I'm sure the other answers are more efficient if you can use the features they do.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [1, 2, 4, 5];
var c = [2, 7, 9];

// takes an array of arrays
function getUnique(input) {

  var unique = [];

  // loop over each array
  input.forEach(function(item) {
    // loop over each value
    item.forEach(function(value) {
      // if it's not already in the unique array,
      if (unique.indexOf(value) == -1) {
        // add it
        unique.push(value);
      }
    });
  });

  return unique;
}

// takes an array of arrays
function getIntersection(input) {

  // assume all elements in first array are common
  var intersection = input.shift();
  var remove = [];

  // loop over items in first array and attempt to
  // disprove commonality
  intersection.forEach(function(value) {

    // loop over subsequent arrays
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      var item = input[i];
      // if these arrays don't contain the value, 
      // then it isn't an intersection
      if (item.indexOf(value) == -1) {
        // add it to an array to be removed
        remove.push(value);
        // exit this loop
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  // remove values determined not to be intersections
  remove.forEach(function(value) {
    intersection.splice(intersection.indexOf(value), 1);
  })

  return intersection;
}


var test = getUnique([a, b, c]);

console.log(test);

var test2 = getIntersection([a, b, c]);

console.log(test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Based on custom forEach and Reduce from previously in the exercise** at http://csbin.io/callbacks

```
function forEach(array, callback) {
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        callback(array[i])
    }
}

function reduce(array, callback, initialValue) {
    for(let i of array){
        initialValue = callback(initialValue, i)
    }
    return initialValue
}

function union(...arrays) {
    return reduce(arrays, (seen, next) => {
        forEach(next, (element) => {
            if(!seen.includes(element)) seen.push(element);
        })
        return seen
    }, [])
}
```

Note if you use the in-built reduce function you can remove the empty inital array  requirement.