# Babel incorrect transformation of spread

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, babeljs, transpiler

Babel incorrectly converting/transpiling the following code

```js
const arr = [...new Set([1, 2, 3, 1])]
```

into

```js
var arr = [].concat(new Set([1, 2, 3, 1]))
```

The first returns a list of numbers, whereas the other returns a list of set(s)

Is this a Babel bug?

Using `@babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.14.6` and `@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.14.7`

Comment: How did you configure Babel? You can try out what it does here: https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: [I don't see that behavior on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/REPL#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gOm2ApgdxgGVcoAKdARgBoYAmWgZlsoF0BKVgKFEhABtcmACYBLBGUQJ2AbiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.17.1&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D).

Comment: What version of Babel are you using? What options (`.babelrc` or similar) are you using? It's ***very*** unlikely you found such a basic bug in Babel, though obviously it's possible. More likely, you have a setting that tells Babel to relax its correctness rules to simplify output.

Comment: What version **of Babel** (not plugins) are you using? And again, what configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it’s related to [**babel/babel#9108** *Correctly transform spreads to use proper concat method*](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/9108), which was merged in [v7.2.2](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.2.2).

As mentioned in [smashercosmo’s comment](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/9108#issuecomment-448201060) on the PR…

> One bad thing about this PR is that before it if somebody tried to spread `Set` in `loose` mode, clear error was thrown, but now he will get wrong output of `[Set()]`, which will be harder to spot.

I think this is exactly what you’re seeing here.  It might be because your Babel config has [`loose`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#loose) set to `true`, maybe, but I’m not sure.

A potential workaround would be to use `Array.from`:

```js
const myArrayWithDupes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];

console.log([...new Set(myArrayWithDupes)]); // your original line
console.log([].concat(new Set(myArrayWithDupes))); // incorrect when `loose` is set to `true`
console.log(Array.from(new Set(myArrayWithDupes))); // a potential workaround
```

Comment: You may be on the right general track, but [just setting `loose` doesn't cause this](https://babeljs.io/REPL#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gOm2ApgdxgGVcoAKdARgBoYAmWgZlsoF0BKVgKFEhABtcmACYBLBGUQJ2AbiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.17.1&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D).

Comment: thanks @rishabh, looks like you have narrowed it down for me

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hmm, looks like you’re right. I’ve updated my answer to only include the workaround.