# In React with Flow Type, [...mySet] does not work but Array.from(mySet) works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

It is React together with Flow Type, I am not sure why

```
{JSON.stringify([...mySet])}
```

won't show the correct values but just show `[{}]`, but then

```
{JSON.stringify(Array.from(mySet))}
```

would show the values.  The strange thing is, I cannot reproduce that in a plain React app:

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-gwen-2xj8gx?file=/src/App.js

and

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-silence-2y32ro?file=/src/App.js

In this case, they both work. Could this be related to what is mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array), and [this issue but it is TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856), not Flow Type, and why would that produce `[{}]`?

Comment: Hi! Here on SO, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: If you can't produce an MRE, we're unlikely to be able to help you. Fundamentally, your two operations should (as you seem to suspect) do exactly the same thing, since sets are iterable, and so `Array.from` uses the set's iterator. If you're not seeing that, then likely the problem is **elsewhere** in the code, not in what's shown. (Particularly if you can't create an MRE for it based on what you're looking at.) That is, it sounds like you need to look elsewhere, not at that operation.

Comment: In any case, your best bet is to [debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/): Make the code `const a = [...mySet]; const s = JSON.stringify(a); /*...later in the JSX...*/ {s}` and put a breakpoint on that first statement, When the breakpoint is hit, examine the contents of `mySet` and step through the code. More: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Good luck finding it! Sounds like no fun. :-(

Comment: *"...won't show the correct values but just show `[{}]`..."*  Are you sure you didn't accidentally leave out the `...`? That is, do you actually have `{JSON.stringify([mySet])}`? That's **exactly** the output you'd get if you forgot the `...`, since sets A) Don't have `toJSON`, and B) Don't have any own, enumerable properties. So `JSON.stringify` just serializes them to the string `{}`, so `[anySet]` ends up being the string `[{}]`.

Comment: those are in fact the whole code: I put side by side `{JSON.stringify([...mySet])}` and `{JSON.stringify(Array.from(mySet))}` and then one works and one doesn't, unlike the codesandbox case. I am sure I did not leave out the `...` by the way. I also tried `[...mySet.values()]` and it is the same issue

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I also added the link to the SO question that says `Array.from()` works better

Comment: One possibility is: if I create a plain set in vanilla JS, `s = new Set()`, and `s.add(1)`, `s.add(3)`, then `JSON.stringify([...s])` gives `[1,3]` but `JSON.stringify([...[s]])` gives `[{}]` so it was transpiled wrong

Comment: No, it wasn't transpiled wrong (in general, [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/tips/#:~:text=%E2%80%9Cselect%E2%80%9D%20Isn%27t%20Broken)). Again: Sets convert to the string `{}` if you gie them to `JSON.stringify`, directly or indirectly. `JSON.stringify([...[s]])` assuming `s` is a set will **always** give you the string `[{}]` (`[...[s]]` becomes `[s]`). Did you see [this comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76342359/in-react-with-flow-type-myset-does-not-work-but-array-frommyset-works#comment134621504_76342359)? From your comment just now, it seems you didn't...?

Comment: I am saying `JSON.stringify([...s])` gave `[{}]` so what's the reason other than it got transpiled wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason.

If you go to [Babel's website](https://babeljs.io/repl) (or try this [saved page](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20ie%208%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwMoFNYF4ZhQdxqqACgG0BGAGgGYBdASgG4AoR0SEAGxQDp2QBzQgCkkAeQByXaACcAlmD4yAZghJc1iAnQYtwEDt14Dh4yVFnylKgIJSpAQwRdFUkHEIa0tL_SA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&modules=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Cflow&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.22.1&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)), make sure to choose "ie 11" (or even ie 8), and then "loose" mode, you'd get the following transpilation:

```js
JSON.stringify([...mySet])
```

is transpiled to:

```js
JSON.stringify([].concat(mySet))
```

which is a wrong transpilation and it is exact reason why the output would show `[{}]`.

You can reproduce it in vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const mySet = new Set([1,3]);

console.log(JSON.stringify([].concat(mySet)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(mySet)));
```

It aimed to create a brand new array using `[].concat(arr)`, but in this case it is a set, so `[].concat(mySet)` becomes an array with a single element which is a Set object.